# Standard deviation with example problem

Tags: standard-deviation

Decide "variance" and "standard deviation" for the following material: 
[material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io8Er.png)

I am using the following formula for "variance".

$$
s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_2 \right)^2 \right)
$$

Where √s^2 = "standard deviation"

12.1*2+12.2*2+12.3*4+12.4+12.5 = 122.7

(12.1*2)^2+(12.2*2)^2+(12.3*4)^2+(12.4)^2+(12.5)^2 = 3911.65

For "variance", s^2, i get:

s^2 = (1/9)*(3911.65-((1/10)*122.7^2) = **267.35**

And for "standard deviation":

√s^2  =  √267.35 = **16.35**

However the correct answer is:

**Standard deviation:** 0.125

**Variance:** 0.0157

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: standard deviation = $\sqrt{\frac{\sum s^2}{n} - (mean)^2}$ where $\sum s^2 $ represents sum of squares of all numbers , n represent total number of terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you come up with $(12.3*4)^2$?

What you wanted was $4(12.3)^2$ which is not the same as $(12.3*4)^2$

Comment: ah I see what i did there ... thanks